# open PowerShell as administrator on specific directory from right-click menu

Tags: powershell, cmd, registry

I need a single command that opens a new elevated PowerShell window on a given path. why? I want a shortcut for opening Powershell as admin on given directory(just like holding shift and right-click on any directory will give you, but as admin.)

I used [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/add-open-command-window-here-back-context-menu-windows-10) to add an "open powershell window as admin here" shortcut to my right-click menu.

currently, I have

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs"
```

that will open elevated PowerShell in C:\WINDOWS\system32 , or:

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'
```

that will open a new not elevated powershell window on current directory

I tried

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs; Set-Location -literalPath '%V'"
```

but it does not navigate to the directory.

note - %v becomes the path inside the directory you right-clicked in it.

How can I combine correctly these commands to open elevated PowerShell in the wanted directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's Windows registry setting; works on rigt-click from Windows Explorer:

```
reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runasPowerShell -s

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runasPowerShell
    HasLUAShield    REG_SZ
    (Default)    REG_SZ    PowerShell here as administrator

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runasPowerShell\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    Powershell Start-Process PowerShell -verb runas -ArgumentList '-noexit', 'Push-Location -literalPath ''""""%V""""'''
```

Note that the tricky quoting `''""""%V""""''` guarantees mistake-free operation even for paths with spaces or other *special* characters.

Answer (score 1):

@JosefZ answer is great, and doing things manually on the registry is possible,

but using [Easy Context Menu v1.6](https://www.sordum.org/7615/easy-context-menu-v1-6/) I could create my wanted context menu much faster and efficiently.

Just go to the List editor and create the sub-menus and items you wish and could create the exact results you wish!

[image]

you can edit things very easily and disable/enable menus whenever you want. you can also show only when holding shift or run as admin.

[image]

see what an elegant result:

[image]

what a wonderful tool!

Comment: Are you trying to sell a GUI product on a coding website? I don't think that's gonna work lol

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I usually also prefer code myself, but why work hard if someone already created a great intuitive GUI tool?

Comment: @EliavLouski, I'm not sure that I'd call it working less hard, when in order to use the GUI tool, you'd still need to know the command/executable, and the argumentlist/parameters. So technically your answer and comment is simply a preference for GUI over CLI, when adding information to the registry, which is why I think Santiago mentioned it.

Comment: @Compo in order to group different items into sub-menu and rearrange them you will need to know much better the different keys and values that available and even if you know it will take more time.

Comment: The question however @EliavLouski, was about creating one context menu entry for a specific purpose, not  how to group and rearrange menu items within a context menu.